# How can I find all of the current stylesheet notebooks?

Tags: front-end, stylesheet, undocumented

I want to find all of the stylesheet notebooks currently open. Is there a modestly fast way to get at this?

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat slow, but it gets the job done:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 sDefs =
  AssociationMap[
   Key["StyleDefinitions"]@*Association@*NotebookInformation,
   FrontEndExecute@
    FrontEnd`ObjectChildren[$FrontEnd]
   ];
 styleNotebooks =
  Cases[Keys@sDefs,
   Alternatives @@
    Flatten[DeleteCases[Values@sDefs, None]]
   ]
 ]

{0.069589, {NotebookObject[Defer[$FrontEnd], 243], 
  NotebookObject[Defer[$FrontEnd], 83], 
  NotebookObject[Defer[$FrontEnd], 220], 
  NotebookObject[Defer[$FrontEnd], 215], 
  NotebookObject[Defer[$FrontEnd], 105], 
  NotebookObject[Defer[$FrontEnd], 4], 
  NotebookObject[Defer[$FrontEnd], 5], 
  NotebookObject[Defer[$FrontEnd], 6], 
  NotebookObject[Defer[$FrontEnd], 75], 
  NotebookObject[Defer[$FrontEnd], 81], 
  NotebookObject[Defer[$FrontEnd], 82], 
  NotebookObject[Defer[$FrontEnd], 104], 
  NotebookObject[Defer[$FrontEnd], 106], 
  NotebookObject[Defer[$FrontEnd], 107], 
  NotebookObject[Defer[$FrontEnd], 186], 
  NotebookObject[Defer[$FrontEnd], 229], 
  NotebookObject[Defer[$FrontEnd], 230]}}
```

It could be made faster if I knew how to get the `NotebookInformation` to vectorize in a single call to the FE, but alas I don't.